# How to differentiate between good information and bad information?

Tags: citations

Suppose, I am writing a research paper on an old controversial topic. I need to interview some old people and need to read some memoirs.

Now, the problem is: the people whom I interview, may be biased, and the part of the memoir may consists of lies.

How can I detect a credible source in this particular case?

Comment: How do your collegues do this?

Comment: This looks like it's about the content of your research, specifically, research methods in "history of some-science". So I would consider it off-topic here.